# Extracting json data from Jmeter http request response

Tags: regex, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I can't find a way to extract array from a json response in Jmeter http request.  All other fields i'm able to extract.  However something like the following i cannot seem to extract.  is there any way i can extract this from response in Jmeter http request?  In the following i need to extract [1,2,3] and save it in a variable.

```
"days":[1,2,3]
"sectionIds":[abc,def,ghi]
```

something like the folliwing i can just extract using "subscriptionId":"(.+?)" in the jmeter regular expression extractor

```
"subscriptionId":"abcd"
```

time value can be extracted using this "time":(\d+)

```
"time": 120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have problem with square braces not being quotted. Try:

> "days":(\[.+?\])

or if you want to match numbers inside something like:

> "days":(\[(\d+,?)+\])

Comment: ^ i'm not sure why it is not showing the escape character in front of brackets in my above comment

Comment: Apparently on SO you have to quote backslashes, that's why they disappeared in my answer too. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Regex way is the best option to deal with JSON data.

There is a plugin called [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) which provides functionality alike to JMeter Embedded [XPATH Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) but targeting JSON.